# Placing two radio buttons adjacent in the cell using grid

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to place  two radio buttons adjacent in a grid cell.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Instantiate a new frame, put this frame in the cell using grid. And then you can instantiate two radio buttons and grid them in the frame.

```
package requite Tk

ttk::label .c11 -text "Cell 1 1"
ttk::label .c12 -text "Cell 1 2"
ttk::label .c13 -text "Cell 1 3"
grid .c11 -row 0 -column 0
grid .c12 -row 0 -column 1
grid .c13 -row 0 -column 2

ttk::label .c21     -text "Cell 2 1"
ttk::frame .frame 
ttk::label .c23     -text "Cell 2 3"
grid .c21   -row 1 -column 0
grid .frame -row 1 -column 1
grid .c23   -row 1 -column 2

    ttk::radiobutton  .frame.rb1 -text "Rb1"
    ttk::radiobutton  .frame.rb2 -text "Rb2"
    grid    .frame.rb1   -row 0 -column 0
    grid    .frame.rb2   -row 0 -column 1

ttk::label .c31 -text "Cell 3 1"
ttk::label .c32 -text "Cell 3 2"
ttk::label .c33 -text "Cell 3 3"
grid .c31 -row 2 -column 0
grid .c32 -row 2 -column 1
grid .c33 -row 2 -column 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is NoonanRosenblum's answer, not mine; I just wanted to make two points about it, and I couldn't fit them into a comment.

1. The `grid` placement doesn't have to be as verbose as in NoonanRosenblum's example.
2. The radiobutton widgets need to have distinct values assigned to work as designed. If they aren't assigned, both buttons will react as one.

---

```
ttk::label .c11 -text "Cell 1 1"
ttk::label .c12 -text "Cell 1 2"
ttk::label .c13 -text "Cell 1 3"
grid .c11 .c12 .c13 

ttk::label .c21 -text "Cell 2 1"
ttk::frame .frame 
ttk::label .c23 -text "Cell 2 3"
grid .c21 .frame .c23   

ttk::radiobutton .frame.rb1 -text Rb1 -value 1
ttk::radiobutton .frame.rb2 -text Rb2 -value 2
grid .frame.rb1 .frame.rb2   

ttk::label .c31 -text "Cell 3 1"
ttk::label .c32 -text "Cell 3 2"
ttk::label .c33 -text "Cell 3 3"
grid .c31 .c32 .c33
```